# Finding a counterexample to cardinality of preimage of a covering map

Tags: algebraic-topology

Consider the fact that if $p: E \rightarrow B$ is a covering map and $B$ is connected, then $|p^{-1}(b)|$ for each $b$ is equal.

I want to test the limits of this proposition, by finding a counter example where $B$ is not connected and this fails. However, I've been stuck on some details.

My idea was to consider $E = A \cup C$ where $A$ and $C$ are disjoint and open in $E$. Similarly $B = D \cup F$. Then I want to define a covering map $p$ such that $A$ is the covering space of $D$ and $C$ the covering space of $F$ such that the cardinalities of the preimages of the elements in $D$ and $F$ are different. But I can't find a specific counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is correct. For each positive integer $k$, the power function $\Bbb C \smallsetminus \{0\} \ni z\mapsto z^k \in \Bbb C \smallsetminus \{0\}$ is a covering map with $k$ sheets. Take the disjoint union of two such mappings corresponding to distinct powers.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B=S^0 = \{1, -1\}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $E = \{(1,1), (1,2), (-1,1)\}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and define $p: E \to B$ to be projection onto the first coordinate.

Comment: More generally, take any surjection between finite sets $S\to T$ and give both sets the discrete topology.

Comment: @KentaS: right. Just (obviously) choose the surjection so that two points in $T$ have preimages with different cardinality.